# Mobile navigation toggle html/css

Tags: html, css, mobile, navigation, toggle

I am creating a mobile navigation that looks like this:
[Mobile navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgbp3.png)

What I would like to do is make the dropdown toggleable, so when I click on housing it drops down but when I click it again it goes back to its original position, I've researched for a while on this but havent found anything that works.

There must be a web guru out there that can easily figure this out.

Thank you!

-Akyx

(Code below)

HTML:

```
 <!-- Mobile nav -->
<nav class="vertical-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Nijmegen&#8964;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="the-area-of-nijmegen.php">The area</a></li>
        <li><a href="useful-information.php">Useful information</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   <li><a href="#">Housing&#8964;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="finding-a-house-nijmegen.php">Finding a house</a></li>
        <li><a href="contract-types.php">Contract types</a></li>
        <li><a href="layout-of-housing.php">Layout of housing</a></li>
        <li><a href="housing-offers.php">Housing offers</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settling in&#8964;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="parking.php">Parking</a></li>
        <li><a href="transportation.php">Transportation</a></li>
        <li><a href="garbage.php">Garbage</a></li>
        <li><a href="settling-in-utilities.php">About Utilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="biking.php">Biking</a></li>
        <li><a href="public-transportation.php">Public Transportation</a></li>
        <li><a href="driving-a-car.php">Driving a car</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Finances&#8964;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="mortgage.php">Mortgage</a></li>
        <li><a href="banking.php">Banking</a></li>
        <li><a href="getting-insured.php">Getting Insured</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Where to go&#8964;</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="events.php">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="musea.php">Musea</a></li>
        <li><a href="food-and-drinks.php">Food and Drinks</a></li>
        <li><a href="where-to-go-meet-up.php">Meet up</a></li>
        <li><a href="where-to-go-sports.php">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="cinemas.php">Cinemas</a></li>
        <li><a href="daily-life.php">Daily life</a></li>
        <li><a href="hotspots.php">Hotspots</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="get-in-touch.php">Get in touch</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav.vertical-nav {
        position: relative;
        background: #000000;
            /*test*/
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

    nav.vertical-nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    nav.vertical-nav li {
        position: relative;
    }

    nav.vertical-nav li li {
        background-color: #7f7f7f;
    }

    nav.vertical-nav a {
        display: block;
        color: #eee;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        transition: 0.2s;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;
    }

    nav.vertical-nav li:hover > a {
        background-color: #4c4c4c;
    }

    nav.vertical-nav ul ul {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
        padding-left: 20px;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    nav.vertical-nav li:hover > ul {
        max-height: 500px;
        transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is to add some basic functionality with JavaScript. 
Here is very simple example of what you are trying to achive with a bit of jquery [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yLhr38dn/3/)

```
$("ul").click(function(){
    $("li").toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for the slideUp/Down animation and not just a toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the CSS `hover`, you could make it work with a Javascript solution. [Pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/NyygBQ).

```
var supportsTouch = "ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints;

if (supportsTouch) {
  $("nav.vertical-nav > ul > li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
  });
} else {
  $("nav.vertical-nav > ul > li").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("expand");
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may choose it as the right answer and/or upvote it so that it will help the community. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mateusz Juruś for leading me in the right direction!

I got it to (kinda) work by changing the Javascript code to this:

```
<script>
$("ul li").click(function(){
$("ul li ul li").toggle(300);});
```

Just still have a problem of having to click twice on the button to open it.
If anyone knows a solution to this I would really appreciate it.

Also do not forgot to add jquery to your header, which I forgot to do.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks again

-Akyx